# Is it possible to compare two gobjects with haskell-gi and find out if they're the same?

Tags: haskell, gtk3

With Gtk2Hs I used to be able to compare gtk objects with `==` to find out whether or not they were the same. For example:

```
boxIsFromState :: VBox -> State -> Bool
boxIsFromState widget state = _widget state == widget
```

Where `State` is a self-defined data type container another VBox.

I noticed `haskell-gi`'s widgets don't derive from `Eq`. Is there another way to compare objects, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: although I am a Haskell expert, I know little about haskell-gi specifically. That said...

Looking at the documentation, we have:

```
newtype Widget = Widget (ManagedPtr Widget)
data ManagedPtr a = ManagedPtr {
    managedForeignPtr :: ForeignPtr a
  , managedPtrIsOwned :: IORef Bool
  }
```

All the appropriate constructors are exported, and both `ForeignPtr` and `IORef` offer `Eq` instances. So it should be trivial to write our own `Eq` instance -- so trivial that the compiler itself should be able to do it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance Eq (ManagedPtr a)
deriving instance Eq Widget
```

Whether this has the right semantics is not 100% clear to me; it's possible that you would want to ignore the ownership for the purposes of your equality tests, in which case you might want to write

```
instance Eq (ManagedPtr a) where
    (==) ManagedPtr { managedForeignPtr = p  }
         ManagedPtr { managedForeignPtr = p' }
         = p == p'
```

or similar instead.

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks a lot!